# Only counting data that fits certain criteria in SQL on Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 1 table in microsoft access with student information (including gender and grade). I'm trying to use the SQL view to get a count of how many male and females are in each grade. Right now, this is what I have.

```
SELECT 
StudDetails.CurrClass as 'class', 
Count(StudeDetails.sex) WHERE (StudDetails.sex="M" AND StudDetails.CurrClass='class') AS 'malecount', Count (StudeDetails.sex) WHERE (StudDetails.sex="F"AND StudDetails.CurrClass='class') AS 'femalecount'
FROM StudDetails
GROUP BY StudDetails.CurrClass;
```

I know this is super bad but I'm new to SQL. I've tried googling but I don't understand the answers or can't apply them.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - afraid Access doesn't have a `case` statement in SQL (well, up to 2010 at least).

Comment: Each `SELECT` statement, no matter how complex, has a single `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER` clause.  Of course, sub-queries are separate `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Could you show a sample of the data - it sounds like a simple solution that shouldn't need `IIF`, correlated or sub-queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `WHERE` the way you're using it. You're looking for `IIF` to do comparisons.

Since `Count` is rather inflexible, using `Sum` and assigning ones and zeroes on a comparison is easier.

```
SELECT 
StudDetails.CurrClass as 'class', 
Sum(IIF(StudDetails.sex="M", 1, 0)) AS malecount, 
Sum(IIF(StudDetails.sex="M", 0, 1))  AS femalecount
FROM StudDetails
GROUP BY StudDetails.CurrClass;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that single-quoting the aliases will produce column names that include the quotes, e.g., `'class'` instead of `class`, which could be a nuisance downstream. Good old square brackets are preferred.

Comment: @GordThompson Oh, I've just copy-pasted those from the sample, they indeed should be removed

Answer (score 1):

Given two fields in the table - *Class* and *Gender*

The table on the left will give the results shown on the right with this SQL:

```
SELECT      Class
            , Sex
            , COUNT(Sex) AS CountOfGender
FROM        StudDetails
GROUP BY    Class, Sex
```

The only downside here is that it won't show `0` if there's none of a certain gender in a class - it just won't show that gender.

```
+-------+--------+  +-------+--------+---------------+
| Class | Sex    |  | Class | Sex    | CountOfSex    |
+-------+--------+  +-------+--------+---------------+
|   A   |    M   |  |   A   |    F   |       2       |
+-------+--------+  +-------+--------+---------------+
|   B   |    M   |  |   A   |    M   |       3       |
+-------+--------+  +-------+--------+---------------+
|   C   |    F   |  |   B   |    M   |       1       |
+-------+--------+  +-------+--------+---------------+
|   A   |    F   |  |   C   |    F   |       1       |
+-------+--------+  +-------+--------+---------------+
|   A   |    M   |  |   D   |    M   |       2       |
+-------+--------+  +-------+--------+---------------+
|   A   |    M   |  
+-------+--------+  
|   D   |    M   |  
+-------+--------+ 
|   D   |    M   |  
+-------+--------+ 
|   A   |    F   | 
+-------+--------+
```

**Edit:**
To get Male & Female in separate fields and include `0` you could then just cross-tab the query above:

```
TRANSFORM NZ(Sum(CountOfSex),0) AS CountOfGender
SELECT Class
FROM (
        SELECT      Class
                    , Sex
                    , COUNT(Sex) AS CountOfSex
        FROM        StudDetails
        GROUP BY    Class, Sex
      )
GROUP BY Class
PIVOT Sex
```

---

```
+-------+---+---+
| Class | F | M |
+-------+---+---+
|   A   | 2 | 3 |
+-------+---+---+
|   B   | 0 | 1 |
+-------+---+---+
|   C   | 1 | 0 |
+-------+---+---+
|   D   | 0 | 2 |
+-------+---+---+
```

**Edit again:**  The good thing about this method above conditionally counting Male & Female (`IIF sex='M'.. etc`) is that if someone decides they don't want to identify as Male or Female it will happily list any other gender you can think of.

```
+-------+---+---+---+
| Class | F | M | Z |
+-------+---+---+---+
|   A   | 2 | 3 | 0 |
+-------+---+---+---+
|   B   | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+-------+---+---+---+
|   C   | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+-------+---+---+---+
|   D   | 0 | 2 | 1 |
+-------+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about ms-access capabilities so these possibilities may not all work for you but at least one should.

```
-- Some sample data

create table StudDetails(sex char(1),currclass varchar(10));

insert into StudDetails values
('M','ClassA'), ('M','ClassA'), ('F','ClassA'),
('F','ClassB'), ('F','ClassB'), ('F','ClassB'), ('M','ClassB'), ('F','ClassB'),
('F','ClassC'), ('F','ClassC');

-- One method

select CurrClass as "class",
       sum(case when sex='M' then 1 else 0 end) as "malecount",
       sum(case when sex='F' then 1 else 0 end) as "femalecount"
  from StudDetails
 group by CurrClass;

-- Another method

with xxx(CurrClass,malecount,femalecount) as
  (
   select CurrClass,1,0 from StudDetails where sex = 'M'
   union all
   select CurrClass,0,1 from StudDetails where sex = 'F'
  )
  select CurrClass,sum(malecount) as malecount,sum(femalecount) as femalecount
    from xxx
    group by CurrClass;

-- Yet another method

select CurrClass,sum(malecount) as malecount,sum(femalecount) as femalecount
  from (
        select CurrClass,1 as malecount,0 as femalecount from StudDetails where sex = 'M'
        union all
        select CurrClass,0 as malecount,1 as femalecount from StudDetails where sex = 'F'
       ) xxx
  group by CurrClass;
```

Comment: In Access SQL, only the last of those options is actually valid (the first one remarkably looks like my answer, but you should use `IIF` instead of `CASE WHEN` in Access).